# What is the latest WordPress that will work on PHP 5.2.17?

Tags: php

I have an old server that runs important PHP aplication that required PHP 5.2.17. What is the newest WordPress that I can install on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at this the wrong way.

Having an old application that requires such a archaic PHP version is bad enough. That does not mean, your new WordPress installation needs to use that same old version though. Instead, I would suggest to **keep PHP 5.2.17 for the legacy application and use the latest PHP version for WordPress**.

There are various ways to do this, it all depends on how exactly your server is set up.

- Check [this answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42719403) for an Apache way. It generally boils down to `AddHandler` and `SetHandler`.
- [This answer from ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/671400/multiple-versions-of-php-through-nginx/671849#671849) explains how to solve it via NGINX. The main idea it seems is to access other ports via `fastcgi_pass`.

Comment: This is most helpful. I didn't know this was possible. - Quick Q without reading into the documentation - do you happen to know offhand if this is possible on Cpanel?

Comment: AFAIK cpanel is only a server management tool, so the answer would be "yes, but it depends on your cpanel/server configuration". If you're not the server administrator, contact that person / your hosting provider for guidance on the specifics.

Comment: Appreciated (can't upvote yet).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [PHP compatibility chart](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/contribute/php-compatibility-and-wordpress-versions/), WordPress version 5.1 is the last version to support PHP 5.2.